# Using awk to convert rows into columns

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, gawk

My data is formatted as such:

```
Row1
<p>{
<p>abc1:a123
<p>abc2:1234
<p>abc3:12345
<p>abc4:abcd
<p>}
<p>Row2
<p>{
<p>abc1:a123
<p>abc2:1234
<p>abc3:12345
<p>abc4:abcd
<p>}
```

I want the output to be as:

```
<p>abc1||abc2||abc3||abc4
<p>a123||1234||12345||abcd
```

I have tried

```
awk 'NR==1 { print $1, $3, $5, $7 } { print $2, $4, $6, $8 } { print $3, $5, $7, $9 } ' RS='\n\n' >FS=': +|\n' OFS='\t'
```

but the command does not convert the entire file as my output is

```
<p>Row1 abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4
<p>{ a123 1234 12345 abcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F '[<>]' '{ print $3 }' file | \
awk -v RS='{' -F '[:\n]' -v OFS='||' \
    'NR > 1 { print "<p>" $2, $4, $6, $8 "</p>\n<p>" $3, $5, $7, $9 "</p>" }'
```

Output:

```
<p>abc1||abc2||abc3||abc4</p>
<p>a123||1234||12345||abcd</p>
<p>abc1||abc2||abc3||abc4</p>
<p>a123||1234||12345||abcd</p>
```

Comment: I placed the <p> and </p> for paragraphs.  Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @pathikrit Can you explain further? What's your actual intended output as a whole?

Comment: I want to load the output into an oracle database for analysis.  Essentially i am able to extract only the first row and my code does not progress further:>awk 'NR >= 1 { print $1, $3, $5, $7, $9, $11, $13, $15, $17, $19 } { print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, $14, $16, $18, $20 } ' RS='\n\n' FS=': +|\n' OFS='||'

Comment: @pathikrit What exactly should be corrected in my script? Is the original input actually different? Can you change it? Can you also show the expected output?

Comment: >awk 'NR >= 1 { print $1, $3, $5} {print $2, $4, $6 } ' RS='{\n' >FS=': +|\n' OFS='|' I got it to work I changed the RS identifier to '{'

Comment: @pathikrit Why not just consider my solution?